# Does Akamai NetStorage has a presigned URL feature

Tags: akamai

Currently, Akamai has many upload mechanisms like FTP, RFTP, NetStorage Api and Aspera.

I would like to know whether Akamai NetStorage has a presigned URL feature-- A presigned URL is a URL that you can provide to your users to grant temporary access to a specific Akamai’s directory, Using the URL, a user can either READ the object or WRITE an Object (or update an existing object)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know NetStorage doesn't have that functionality out of the box, however you could implement that using Edge logic. Basically you create an Akamai Edge Configuration that uses NetStorage as origin and enforces Edge URL authentication.

You can generate the tokens using the App of your choice (i.e. AWS or Azure), and then have the token validated on the Akamai Edge. Feel free to contact [Akamai Technical support](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/support/) if you need more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your architecture. Netstorage is Read/Writeable - subject to correct authentication headers accompanying your "presigned" URL. Such access to NetStorage is NOT scaleable. So if you just want to give a URL to many users, then you simply need a property configured in Akamai to do what you want.